# Activity view is differnet than emualtor and not showing toolbar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I've suddenly noticed that my activity view got messed up somehow until recently it was ok, meaning the toolbar was visible and no gap was under the 'end with' textbox.
what's weird is that I have another activity where I do see the toolbar and the view is fine. 
So, in conclusion, my main problem with this view is that the toolbar is missing, there is an unwanted gap under the 'end with' textbox. As you can see in the attached pictures there is no correlation between the XML viewer and the activity view on the emulator.

What could be the reason for that? I ran out of ideas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="corp.blayzer.randomit.SubmitNumbersActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:background="@color/mainBackGroundHalf1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/minVal_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/minVal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/inputText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/minValue"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material"
            android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/maxVal_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minVal_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/maxVal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/inputText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/maxValue"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material"
            android:textColorHint="@color/inputText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textChoiceView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
    android:text="@string/instructionsMainAct"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
    android:textColor="@color/choicesOfNum"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layOutBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textChoiceView">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_change_history_black_24dp"
        tools:text="@string/GoButton" />
</FrameLayout>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: XML view]

[image: Emulator view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had another layout v26/activity_send_numbers for that activity, that for some reason my emulator kept on using although my device APK was lower. I've Updated/Deleted that layer and all my issues went away. I realized that my code is ok once I've added another FAB and it was not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change height attribute for `Toolbar` element:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed

Comment: You need to wrap your layout into `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ConstraintLayout` as your root container, each widgets should be constrained correctly. The Outermost layer should be [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) . Here is a [example](https://www.loopwiki.com/ui-ux-design/android-coordinatorlayout-examples/).